# What is the better way to filter out record selections in a form based on user input? _afterupdate or _beforeupdate?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, filter, record

new to Access.

Here is the form layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l99l0.png

You can see there is 1 main project page with 6 different subforms in each tab (subform 2-7), all with their own table.

They are linked by Project Number (primary key) and Request Number.

The main purpose of this form is to record information for a specific project (Project Number: Unique) over the course of many meetings (Request Number: starts at 1).

For example, I want to record important information about project 101 and this is the 4th meeting we're having about it.

Some of the subforms could have many different records. For example, a customer could be talking about 11 different new data sources and so for project 101, request: 4, there would be 11 records for tab/subform 5.

I want a way where when the user puts in a Project Number and a Request Number, it pulls up the existing records for those.

I used this combobox trick for the main project management page (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSPS24EfijI), but this will not work with tabs/subforms 2-7.

So I thought about using the following guide from Microsoft:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/locate-specific-records-in-a-database-e186238d-e4d7-4918-92a0-1236661c6f58

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.filter(property)

Is it better to do it at the main page level:

```
Private Sub RequestNumber_AfterUpdate()
Page2.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
Page2.Filter = "RequestNumber = 'Me.RequestNumber.Value'"

Page3.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
Page3.Filter = "RequestNumber = 'Me.RequestNumber.Value'"

Page4.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
Page4.Filter = "RequestNumber = 'Me.RequestNumber.Value'"

Page5.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
Page5.Filter = "RequestNumber = 'Me.RequestNumber.Value'"

Page6.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
Page6.Filter = "RequestNumber = 'Me.RequestNumber.Value'"

Page7.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
Page7.Filter = "RequestNumber = 'Me.RequestNumber.Value'"

Page2.FilterOn = True
Page3.FilterOn = True
Page4.FilterOn = True
Page5.FilterOn = True
Page6.FilterOn = True
Page7.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Or at the subform level?

```
Private Sub ProjectNumber_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Me.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
Me.Filter = "RequestNumber = 'Me.RequestNumber.Value'"


Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Both options didn't work with nothing changing. Should I be calling the form name? Tab control? The page of the tab?

Also, it shouldn't matter if I call on the project/request number in the main form or the subforms because they're all linked together, right? Aka, whatever I put in the main form gets cascaded down to the subforms.

Thank you.

Comment: Two pieces of advice. 1. You generally should only use `BeforeUpdate` if you want to validate data before it is saved on a table. For everything else use `AfterUpdate`, `OnChange` or `OnLostFocus` depending on the exact behavior you are looking for. 2. Any form control that is used for selecting or filtering should be `unbound` and any form control that contains data used to link between two tables should be `locked`.

Comment: Also review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Tab control pages do not have filter property. Forms and reports have filter property. Do subforms have relationship with main form? Master/Child Links properties of subform/subreport container should synchronize records. Must reference subform and its properties through the container control that holds form.

Comment: Huh that is very unusual, it wasn't synchronized for me earlier. I deleted the relationship and retried it and it synchronizes now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at my note for generic advice but specifically:

```
Page2.Filter = "ProjectNumber = 'Me.ProjectNumber.Value'"
```

is wrong. use

```
Page2.Filter = "ProjectNumber = '" & Me.ProjectNumber & "'"
```